# Reading from a file in TCL exclusively

Tags: file, tcl

I need to read from a report file (simple textual report file), but it may be that the file is still being generated - so I need to wait. Essentially wait and read from the file when all other processes that are writing to it have finished - is there a way to do this in TCL?

**MORE INFO:**
The process that writes the report file is third party - I have no control over it.  I start reading towards the end of the reporting cycle and the launching of my reads is controlled by a parent third party app - so I cannot delay my reading. Isn't there a way in TCL to query if the file is open or being updated etc. ? And I could wait for that status to clear?

Comment: I'd say depends on how much the other processes are writing at a time. If they write a chunk of information every 5 minutes, I would check the file size every 5 minutes and if it did not increase between each check, then start working on the file. It'd be simpler if you could somehow get the other process to tell Tcl it is done, but I don't have experience with that.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Maybe if you make the report file into a named pipe. The third party process would open the pipe as write-only and your TCL as read-only. If the TCL blocks when attempting to read the pipe the third party process is not done writing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a local file, and you're running on a somewhat POSIX platform (e.g., Linux or macOS) then you can use `lsof -t` (**l**i**s**t by **o**pen **f**iles, **t**ersely) to find what processes have the file open.

```
# A slightly weird way of calling because we ignore the errors
set thefile /path/to/thefile.data
set pids {}
catch {
    set pids [exec lsof -t $thefile]
}
```

That will set `pids` to the list of processes (by ID) that have the file; if you have it open, it will include the current process! You might or might not care about that.

Be aware: this is an expensive operation. It may take multiple seconds to generate the PID list.

Comment: I've no way to check how methods for doing the equivalent on Windows would work.